# Appropriate distribution for rate data for regression in R

Tags: r, distributions, poisson-distribution, random-effects-model, poisson-regression

I am developing a regression model that investigates how environmental factors impact death rate. The number of deaths was counted over the course of a season, however, the season length (and therefore the number of days over which dead animals were counted) varied. Therefore, my response variable is calculated as a daily death rate: number of dead animals/population size/number of days counted.

I understand that if I were simply modeling the number of deaths counted, it would be appropriate to use a Poisson regression. However, I am unsure how to model this new response rate. As you can see from the histogram below, there are many zeros:

[image]

If possible, I would also like to include random effects in my model. Any suggestions on how to model this in R would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: why not use an offset rather than dividing? That way you don't muck up the variance

Comment: Is it acceptable to use 2 offsets, for both population size and # of days counted?

Comment: `?offset` (see "Details") ... note that offsets are *additive* not multiplicative but they work on the level of the linear predictor (i.e. in a log-link, you're working on the scale of the log-mean). So you just put each offset term in as its log. so something like `y~x1+x2+offset(log(popsize))+offset(log(numdays))` should work as would `y~x1+x2+offset(log(popsize)+log(numdays))` and you can use the `offset` argument in glm as well: `y~x1+x2,offset=(log(popsize)+log(numdays))`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Turns out my data is overdispersed as well, so I think I should actually use a negative binomial model...